# How do I implement site-wide exception handling in a spring MVC architecture?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, spring-security

**Note:**  Skip to the two updates at the bottom to find the answer.

I have a Spring (3) MVC web application running on Tomcat.  This web application serves as a UI for a remote WSDL service layer.  I have written a custom AuthenticationProvider to authenticate to this remote service.  That works fine.  My issue is this:

Each controller method, more or less, results in a remote call to this remote WSDL.  My plan was to not have Tomcat or Spring expire sessions, but wait until the remote server tells me that the session has expired on that end and then re-route the user to the login page, telling them that their session has expired.

BaseController, from which all other Controllers extend, has this method:

```
protected void addBindingErrors(HttpSession session, MTAResponse response, BindingResult binding, boolean allowDefault) {
switch (response.getResponseCode()) {
case SESSION_EXPIRED:
     UserInfo nfo = (UserInfo)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
     SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
     System.out.println("token in handle session expired: " + nfo.getMtaCoreSessionId());
     if(session != null){
          System.out.println("invalidating session");
          session.invalidate();
          //1.  throw new SessionAuthenticationException("session expiredd");
          ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("error");
          throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mav);
          //3.  something else?
     }
     context.setAuthentication(null);
  break;      
case INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE:
  binding.addError(...);
  break;
case ACCESS_DENIED:
  binding.addError(...);
  break;          
default:
  if(allowDefault){
    binding.addError(...);
    break;
  }
}
```

}

I have found a couple solutions, but I'm new to Spring so I don't know if they're the "right" ones or if there are issues lurking in them.

1. (a bit of a cheat) In the BaseController.addBindingError() method, if a remote session expired code is received, throw a SessionAuthenticationException

   - Pros:  this works, automagically re-routes the user to login page (I think because I have authentication-failure-url set?)
   - Cons:  I’d have to change the signature of addBindingError to throw this kind of exception.
   - Con: I’d also have to change the signature of every controller method to throw this kind of exception, since they all make remote service calls to WSDL.
   - Con:  the user doesn’t know why they’re back at the login page and I’m not sure there is a way to let them know
2. In the BaseController.addBindingError() method, if a remote session expired code is received, throw a ModelAndViewDefiningException

   - Pros:  this works, automagically re-routes the user to appropriate error page, which can contain a link to the login page
   - Pro: we can explain to the user on this page how they got here.
   - Cons:  I’d have to change the signature of addBindingError to throw this kind of exception.
   - Con: I’d also have to change the signature of every controller method to throw this kind of exception, since they all make remote service calls to remote WSDL
3. In the BaseController.addBindingError() method, if a remote session expired code is received, throw a MyCustomRemoteSessionExpiredException and then catch it in a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

   - Pros:  this works, automagically re-routes the user to appropriate error page, which can contain a link to the login page
   - Pro: we can explain to the user on this page how they got here.
   - Cons:  I’d have to change the signature of addBindingError to throw this kind of exception.
   - Con: I’d also have to change the signature of every controller method to throw this kind of exception, since they all make remote service calls to remote WSDL

Numbers 2 and #3 have the same pros/cons.  #3 seems like it might be a more "correct" solution.  Does anyone have any feedback, suggestions, or alternatives?

**Update 5/30/2013:**

I think I may have found what I'm looking for and I think it will require me to upgrade to the latest spring 3.2.  @ControllerAdvice  a la this article here:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/exception-handling-with-the-spring-3-2-controlleradvice-annotation.html 
From BaseController.addBindingError, I'll throw MyCustomException (which extends RuntimeException so that the method signatures will not need to declare a throws statement) and handle that in a new @ControllerAdvice class (which will contain an @ExceptionHandler method).
Can anyone confirm or deny this approach?
Any better suggestions?

Thanks!

**Update 12/3/2013 ****

This question would have been much better titled like so: "How do I implement site-wide exception handling in a spring MVC architecture?".  So, I'm changing the title (the former title was based on my misunderstanding that the interaction with the remote SOAP server had anything to do with my real question).  I implemented the solution discussed in May and it has been working very well.  I have even extended the @ControllerAdvice class to handle other RuntimeExceptions.

Comment: #1: Spring's `SessionAuthenticationException` is a `RuntimeException`, so it won't force you to change the signature. #3 If you make `MyCustomRemoteSessionExpiredException` a `RuntimeException`, you won't need to change the method signatures.

Comment: Each call to WS return MTAResponse object?

Comment: @Maksym: yes, each call will be an MTAResponse object or a subclass of it.

Comment: ok, good point about the RuntimeExceptions, that would be appropriate here. Also someone mentioned @ExceptionHandler, which I need to look into.